# How to generate polygon dimensions with the least effort?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I found this page https://www.bridgersteel.com/metal-colors/roof-visualizer where there is an interactive way to change the color of a demo house and see how it looks like.

As far as I know, they used a pretty straightforward and simple way of doing this.

However, what I don't understand is how did they produced the exact super-precise polygon points. Is there a non-manual way of doing this?
Otherwise, even basic, this job requires ton of days to be made...

Do you have any hints?

[image]

Comment: There are tools/editors that edit vector (.svg) images, such as [inkscape](https://inkscape.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess they used vector graphics software, like Adobe Illustrator, to create the svg. Depending on the software, you can even see the code it generates. You can also convert an svg image to code using javascript on the website itself.

Answer (score 0):

I visited the page and came up with the following in the link below.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1PQimeXKGyCJd1lNZHHHuOkOhLc3oq97v